# IntelliJ Idea, Play SBT project and dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 14 CE. It has a nice built-in integration with SBT and so, once I've created my Play project with activator I'm able to work on it, debug it and so on.
Now, I've added a library dependency in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j" % "4.0.4"
```

Running `activator run` from the command line, I see that it is resolved correctly.
The problem is that Idea doesn't see it. In the list of "External libraries", i see no `SBT: or.twitter4j` as I'd expect and in fact the IDE doesn't let me `import` it.

I've already tried the "Refresh" button from the SBT Window with no results.

Comment: If you open properties and go to: Build, Exe, Deploy > Build Tools > SBT, what checkboxes are checked there in `Project level settings` And is your project listed there below header 'Linked SBT Projects'

Comment: @adis No checkbox is checked there. The project is correctly linked under "Linked SBT Projects"

Comment: I think you should check `Auto import` there.. With this setting IntelliJ will sync the project with libs defined in .sbt files.

Comment: This is what helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912479/play-framework-package-javax-inject-does-not-exist

Comment: I usually import libraries manually into intelliJ from the play local repository. That way, the IDE is able to resolve it and play anyway works fine from command line.