# Play Framework: [Error] object inject is not a member of package javax

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

My play framework application is all of a sudden throwing the following errors during compilation:

```
[error] /Users/ihorton/Client Work/DPaaS/coursera-scala/cookbook/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:5:14: object inject is not a member of package javax
[error] import javax.inject._
[error]              ^
[error] /Users/ihorton/Client Work/DPaaS/coursera-scala/cookbook/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:11:2: trait Singleton is abstract; cannot be instantiated
[error] @Singleton
[error]  ^
[error] /Users/ihorton/Client Work/DPaaS/coursera-scala/cookbook/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:12:23: not found: type Inject
[error] class HomeController @Inject()(controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(controllerComponents) {
[error]                       ^
           ^
```

Here is my use of `javax.inject`, `@Inject` and `@Singleton` in code:

```
import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class RecipeController @Inject()(controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(controllerComponents) {
...
```

I've read through what looks to be the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912479/play-framework-package-javax-inject-does-not-exist), but trying sbt `reload` prior to `compile` doesn't work for me.

What's puzzling, unless I'm misreading the Play Framework 2.8.x documentation, is that it seems like javax.inject should be packaged with Play out of the box. So I'm not sure why this object would be missing.

I'm using the following versions:

- Play: 2.8.8
- Scala: 2.13.6
- JDK: 17.0.1

Here's my build.sbt file to which I've added `javax.inject` which doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

```
name := """cookbook"""
organization := "com.ian-horton"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "commons-io"             %  "commons-io"         % "2.5",
  "javax.inject"           % "javax.inject"        % "1",
  "net.sourceforge.tess4j" % "tess4j"              % "5.0.0",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0"  % Test,
  "org.specs2"             %% "specs2-core"        % "4.13.0" % Test)
```

Happy to provide additional detail if need be.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Finding this other [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718662/cant-locate-import-javax-inject-inject-package) I followed the steps manually added the Maven dependency for Javax.Inject to my project in Intellij which fixed the problem.

I'm keeping this question open though in the hopes that someone can perhaps shed some light on why this dependency isn't pulled in with Play.

Comment: Here you have a minimal ready example https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/app/controllers/HomeController.scala

Comment: @vmartin I've edited my post above with the code from my controller. It appears to be the same as your example. Any ideas about what might be resulting in the error?